# Найти файл, не зная расширения

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Как используя `fs.readFile()` можно найти файл, если известно только его название, без расширения?

Например, есть код, ищущий картинку в папке:

```js
fs.readFile(`${process.cwd()}/picture_db/${id}`, (err, data) => {
  console.log(data, err);
})
```

Здесь `id` равно названию картинки. Выводит ошибку, хотя файл с таким названием явно есть в папке.

Comment: [Получаем список файлов](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) и сравниваем  с нужным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить все файлы из папки и пробежаться по ним:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(`${process.cwd()}/picture_db/`, (err, files) => {
  const image = files.find((name) => {
    const unescapedId = id.replace(/[\\\/.+*?(){}^$]/g, '\\$&');
    return new RegExp('^' + unescapedName + '(?=\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif|svg|webp))$').test(name);
  });
  console.log(image);
});
```

или

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(`${process.cwd()}/picture_db/`, (err, files) => {
  const image = files.find((name) => {
    const nameValue = name.split('.').slice(0, -1);
    return nameValue.join('.') === id;
  });
  console.log(image);
});
```

Comment: А если в папке окажутся файлы `1.png` и, например, `1.old.png`?

Comment: @Yaant поправил